# LaTeX - tables, multirow with non integer number of rows

Tags: tables, multirow

**Editted to provide a clearer example**

Basically I want to make a table that in one column has a series of dates and the second and third columns have a series of objectives for that date. However the number of elements in the second and third column are not the same, and do not share a common factor, however I want all three columns to be equally spaced vertically. In other words the vertical distance between the `2011-2012` should be the same to both `Training 1` and `Training 2`, and they should be between the Objectives.

So, for example, what I want to do is:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l c c|}
    \hline
    Year & Objective & Training \\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{2011-2012} & Objective 1 & \multirow{1.5}{*}{Training 1} \\
                         & Objective 2 &                               \\
                         & Objective 3 & \multrow{1.5}{*}{Training 2}  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

To look something like:

```
             Year         Objective     Training
                          Objective 1
                                        Training 1
             2011-2012    Objective 2
                                        Training 2
                          Objective 3
```

But with the vertical space between `Objective`s compressed. Obviously this doesn't work as multirow expects an integer number. Is there another command where a non-integer number would work, or a work around to get the effect that I desire.

What is the best way of doing something like this?

**Additional edit**

This needs to be scalable, so that I can take any three numbers I choose and be able to make an evenly spaced table e.g.

[image]

The colours do not need to be replicated, they are merely illustrative (plus are easy enough to do via colorx). The top row are the titles, the multi-coloured segments are columns with a different number of elements (the number of elements in each column is stated in the title).

Comment: Oh - and it would be nice if the solution worked within tabularx - or some other format that allowed each section to span multiple rows, but even outside that I am curious if there is a work around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly what you're doing is fine, but your use of the [`multirow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) and associated `\multirow` command is incorrect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l c c|}
    \hline
    Year & Objective & Training \\
    \hline
    \multirow{5}*{2011-2012} & Objective 1 & \multirow{2}*{Training 1} \\
                         & Objective 2 &                               \\
                         & Objective 3 & \multirow{3}*{Training 2}  \\
                         & Objective 4 &                               \\
                         & Objective 5 &                               \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

In its simplest form, the use is `\multirow{<num rows>}{<width>}{<stuff>}` where `<num rows>` is an *integer* denoting the number of rows to spread `<stuff>` across. A `<width>` of `*` denotes the natural width of `<stuff>`.

Just in terms of presentation, you could also use [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). The motivation being that vertical lines are not required since the structure inherent in a table is columnar, so there's no need to pursue the use of vertical rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l c c}
    \toprule
    Year & Objective & Training \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{5}*{2011-2012} & Objective 1 & \multirow{2}*{Training 1} \\
                         & Objective 2 &                               \\
                         & Objective 3 & \multirow{3}*{Training 2}  \\
                         & Objective 4 &                               \\
                         & Objective 5 &                               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

---

Following your edit, you can still specify integer values to have `\multirow` entries in the way you present:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l c c|}
    \hline
    Year & Objective & Training \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}*{2011-2012} & Objective 1 & \multirow{2}*{Training 1} \\
                         & Objective 2 & \multirow{2}*{Training 2} \\
                         & Objective 3 & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Moreover, the same output as above is obtained if you even use a negative number of rows for `\multirow`. That is, to use the following `tabular` setup:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l c c|}
    \hline
    Year & Objective & Training \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}*{2011-2012} & Objective 1 & \multirow{2}*{Training 1} \\
                         & Objective 2 & \\
                         & Objective 3 & \multirow{-2}*{Training 2}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

---

Final edit update:

Centering content within a table is also possible via the `m`-column type from the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). So, in order to duplicate the result (without colours and lines/rules), here's one way of doing it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcolumntype{C}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2em}}}
  \toprule
  A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J \\
  \midrule
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{C}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10\end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not what I want - I want the third column to be evenly spaced, as is the case in the 1st and 2nd column. I want `Training 1` to be halfway between `Objective 2` and `Objective 3`, similarly `Training 2` to be halfway between `Objective 3` and `Objective 4`. I have now edited the initial question in an attempt to be more clear.

Comment: I have now amended the question to try and be more clear - also realised that what I suggested in the previous comment is incorrect, the even spacing would have `Training 1` in line with `Objective 2`, and `Training 2` in line with `Objective 3`. Therefore for this case there is a direct work around, without the need for `\multirow`. However, this was just the simplest case I had in my table - and happened to also have a simple answer.

Comment: @DavidDuncan: See the end of my answer for an update on this. Does it address your question?

Comment: I'm afraid not - that method doesn't scale - this 1 / 3 / 2 is merely the simplest possible example, I want something that is a general solution for any feasible combination. Additionally, cosmetically the spacing isn't right - the spacing between `Training 1` and `Training 2` is smaller than the spacing above and below.

Comment: I have now updated the question to include a link to an image (which due to only have a rating of 6 on Tex I cannot put the image here directly) showing a table with 10 columns, increasing in the number of elements per column.

Comment: Actually I think I'm wrong - it is scale-able - it just means that I have to be very exact with my placement and numbering in multirow.

Comment: @DavidDuncan: Yes, that's true. You have to be exact with your placement *and* numbering in `\multirow`. If you can manually perform the placement, then the numbering can be automated (always being `1` or `2`). Or, if you can figure out the numbering manually, then the placement can be automated. However, this seems to have solved your problem.

Comment: @DavidDuncan: I've added some alternate take on your "scalable example" containing the image. Not sure whether that would help.